# Why don't we need to call $scope.$apply in angular-meteor tutorial step 16 for marker.events.dragend()?

Tags: angular-google-maps, angular-meteor

[Step 16 of angular-meteor tutorial](http://angular-meteor.com/tutorial/step_16)

```
$scope.map = {
      center: {
        latitude: 45,
        longitude: -73
      },
      zoom: 8,
      events: {
        click: function (mapModel, eventName, originalEventArgs) {
          if (!$scope.party)
            return;

          if (!$scope.party.location)
            $scope.party.location = {};

          $scope.party.location.latitude = originalEventArgs[0].latLng.lat();
          $scope.party.location.longitude = originalEventArgs[0].latLng.lng();
          //scope apply required because this event handler is outside of the angular domain
          $scope.$apply();
        }
      },
      marker: {
        options: { draggable: true },
        events: {
          dragend: function (marker, eventName, args) {
            if (!$scope.party.location)
              $scope.party.location = {};

            $scope.party.location.latitude = marker.getPosition().lat();
            $scope.party.location.longitude = marker.getPosition().lng();
          }
        }
      }
    };
```

Why don't we need to call `$scope.$apply();` at the end of marker.events.dragend function but we need to call `$scope.$apply();` at the end of events.click function?

Note that I know we need to call `$scope.$apply();` at the end of events.click function because this callback is called by Google Map API.  Isn't marker.events.dragend function a callback that is going to be called by Google Map API as well?